# I want to create a loop within a class

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a variable 'beta'. I want to run the code with 1000 different values of 'beta' that range between 0 and 1. My first thought was to run a loop but I am unable to do this within a class. I also have tried using pointers but this did not seem to work. I apologise if my question is rather amateur but I am a Math grad, not computer science. Can someone please help!
The code for my class is listed below.

```
class FalknerSkan : public MFunction
{
public:
    //constuctor to initialise kappa
    FalknerSkan() {beta = 0.0;}

    MVector operator()(const double& x, const MVector& y)
    {//y[0]=f, y[1]=f', y[2]=f'', y[3]=Z1, y[4]=Z2, y[5]=Z3
        MVector temp(6);
        temp[0] = y[1];
        temp[1] = y[2];
        temp[2] = -y[0]*y[2] - beta*(1-y[1]*y[1]);
        temp[3] = y[4];
        temp[4] = y[5];
        temp[5] = -y[2]*y[3] + 2.0*beta*y[1]*y[4] - y[0]*y[5];
        return temp;
    }
    void SetKappa(double k) {beta = k;} //change kappa
private:
    double beta; // class member variable, accessible within
    //all FalknerSkan member functions

};
```

Thank you

Comment: How are you "unable" to use a loop? Also, it's next to impossible to tell what most of what you posted does. This appears to be a math function that you've not explained, which makes it hard to tell what the intended function is.

Comment: What exactly is "the code" that you want to run with 1000 different values of 'beta'? Is it the operator?

Comment: Ok sorry if my explanation was not clear. This class returns a vector of derivatives based on an equation known as the 'Falkner Skan equation.' In my main(), these derivatives (temp[ ]) will be used. Obviously I get different values depending on beta so I want to run 1000 simulations with different values of beta. (Beta= 0.001, 0.002, 0.003.... 1) Rather than manually typing a new value every time I figured a loop would be the best option

Comment: @George, a class can't return data. You mean its member functions. Also, this is not helpful. More info is needed. You can of course describe the problem from mathematical perspective however your sample code is not clear.

Comment: In my main I need to use a class f. I call this class by 'FalknerSkan f'. This function will change depending on the value Beta so I need to run the simulation with 1000 different functions

Comment: @George, please state your problem clearly. As I said, if you are not able to explain it from programming perspective, state the math problem directly. People will help you with the coding. Otherwise, I might downvote it since it is not clear what is the problem. Also, your post will be put on hold for the worst scenario.

Comment: It is very hard to explain to be totally honest. I am struggling to write a project that explains how this method works so I don't think I will be able to clarify it now. Sorry if my question has been unclear. I appreciate your help

Comment: @George, post the entire code or at least the errors. Otherwise, hire someone for the programming matter. Sorry you left me no choice expect to downvote it till you edit your post to reflect the real issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a loop inside a class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : beta(0.0) 
    {}

    void print(){
        for (int i(0); i < 1000; ++i)
            std::cout << ++beta << std::endl;
    }

private:
    double beta; 
};

int main()
{
    Foo obj;
    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working because you are not stating the problem clearly. No one can help you with that.